# Raspberry Pi 7 inch capacitive touch drivers

Tags: screen

I have bought [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/7inch-HDMI-LCD-800-480-Capacitive-Touch-Screen-LCD-for-Raspberry-Pi-2-Banana-Pi/231587697897?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3Dfb1feb6a44de4d479dffaa0bc09cb857%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D261893273900) capacitive touch screen and it comes with an image of Raspbian (i think) already with the touch drivers installed.

I wonder if anyone know where I can find the correct drivers for this particular touch so I can install them in other distribution?

Comment: Drivers are automatically loaded with the kernel. So you have to do trial and error to see if other distros will support it.

Comment: What do you see when you run `lsusb` ? It should list all the usb devices connected along with device description.

Comment: `lusb` gives me this:  `ID 0eef:0005 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd` I have already searched for drivers to this but I didn't find any

Comment: This is from `dmesg`:  `input: RPI_TOUCH By ZH851 as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.3/1-1.5.3:1.0/input/input2`

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a Waveshare 7" touchscreen which I recently bought as well.  I had some problems with the kernels that they provided in that they disabled my GPIO access from python, but I found someone who wrote there own drivers for this.  See this answer for a link to the driver and see if it works for you:

[Touchscreen drivers disable GPIO interface in Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36151/touchscreen-drivers-disable-gpio-interface-in-python/36281#36281)

They tested it for Raspbian-Wheezy, and thats what I used in on too, but maybe it'll work for other distributions.  You may be able to contact the driver's creator too for more functionality.