# Can not use GPIO pins when Official Raspberry Pi screen is connected

Tags: gpio, pi-2, linux, wiringpi, dsi

I have a Raspberry Pi2 B+ model, with noobs distro installed.

I had some programs using wiringPi library and an ultrasound component working (tested them using a separate monitor via HDMI). However, after connecting the official Raspberry Pi touch screen display these programs are not working anymore.

On further analysis I realized that the ECHO signal from same ultrasound device was never captured (checked using voltage value on one of the INPUT mode GPIO pins)

Referred to questions:
[GPIO pins NOT working when using touchscreen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36866/gpio-pins-not-working-when-using-touchscreen)
and
[Touchscreen drivers disable GPIO interface in Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36151/touchscreen-drivers-disable-gpio-interface-in-python/36281#36281)

However, I don't think this is the problem because if I disconnect the touch screen and plug in HDMI again, the same programs with same ultrasound connections work flawlessly. (Note: also tried a simple LED program, but that doesn't work either)

Any ideas? The questions I referred to mentioned that the drivers for touchscreen might have disabled the kernel level access for GPIO library (Python library in those questions, wiringPi C library in my case)
I just did a full update and upgrade from apt-get to get the screen working, no special drivers installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a fresh raspbian jesse instead of updating?
And are all the flatcables connected in the screen. I had a couple delivered to me where the smallest cable was disconnected from the board.